# pharo webapp hosting with multiple instances

Tags: web-applications, web-hosting, pharo

How to host a web app with Pharo so that every client accessing it on the web has a unique instance of the application?

I made a web app based on the 'Enterprise Pharo' example which serves an html page on ZnServer like so:

```
ZnServer startDefaultOn: 80. 
ZnServer default delegate map: #display to: RBDisplay new.
```

The site can be found, for example, on localhost/display

The page I made and hope to host online accepts a .csv file, iterates values within it to return a new value, and returns it as a table with this new value placed in a column. While this part works for me, I've found that the values uploaded persist no matter when or where I access the page I've hosted (i.e. other computers, ip addresses, times) unless I restart the ZnServer.

What would be the best way to host this sort of app, so that everyone who visits the page gets served a 'fresh' instance of my application?

Answer (score 0):

With Seaside you get sessions for free. You can then put a load balancer in front of your nginx/apache and make sure your sessions are always routed to the right image.

Answer (score 0):

Partially Solved.

Grabbed the unique session ID with  `sessionID := request session` and rendered a new instance of a subclass and mapped to delegate server followed by `ZnClient Redirect: sessionID` to that instance.

Expired sessions then need to be cleaned up.